# Replacing the "x" in Data Frame Multiple Response Columns before Reshaping Using Tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tidyr

Below is a simple data frame.

```
Program <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
Apartment <- c("x","","","x","")
House <- c("x","","x","","")
Condo <- c("","x","","","x")
Cat <- c("x","","x","","")
Dog <- c("","x","","","")
Fish <- c("","x","","x","x")

DF1 <- data.frame(Program,Apartment,House,Condo,Cat,Dog,Fish)
```

Using this data frame, I would like to use Tidyr to create the table below. The table provides counts for the number of each pet by accommodation. So for those with an apartment, there is one instance of a cat, and one instance of a fish.

In order to accomplish this, I first have to replace the "x's" with the pet name for each column before melting the data. I would like to know how to do this across all columns in one line of code, or one function.

I'm also having trouble using Tidyr, or Reshape2, to create the table in the exact form below. (*The table below doesn't exactly line up, but each number should be below the pet name. So for the first row, the 1 should be under cat, the 0 under dog, and the 1 under fish, etc...)*

```
      variable         Cat      Dog    Fish 
1     Apartment          1        0       1
2     House              2        0       0
3     Condo              0        1       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF1 %>% 
    gather(House, Val, Apartment:Condo) %>% 
    filter(Val!="") %>% 
    gather(Animals, Val2, Cat:Fish) %>%
    group_by(House, Animals) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum(.!='')), Val:Val2)  %>%
    spread(Animals, Val2) %>%
    select(-Val)   
#      House   Cat   Dog  Fish
#      <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1 Apartment     1     0     1
#2     Condo     0     1     2
#3     House     2     0     0
```

Comment: Actually, a quick question. I'm just playing around with this on some real data, and I realize that I have NA's instead of blank spaces. I'm getting an error "invalid "type" (character) of argument" and also that attributes are not identical. My data frame is similar to the example data used above. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I think I need to replace the NA's with 0's or blank spaces.

Comment: @Mike If you you want to replace the NAs, do `DF1[] <- lapply(DF1, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))`

Comment: Thanks! I tried but I got this error - - - In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = 0) : invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @Mike Sorry, didn't know that you had factor columns, convert to character and it should work, i.e. `DF1[] <- lapply(DF1, function(x) replace(as.character(x), is.na(x), 0))`

Comment: Thanks again for the help, but it didn't work. I tried converting the factors to character, but no 0's appeared. I tried it on the example data frame above. Not sure why.

Comment: @Mike Please check whether the NAs are infact real NAs.  You check by `is.na(DF1)`.  If there are TRUE values, it is NA.

Comment: I got it working. I used a wrong data frame that didn't have any NA's lol.  It's late so I wasn't thinking clearly. All is good now so thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Base version:

```
tmp <- data.frame(DF1[-1]=="x")
tmp <- data.frame(stack(tmp[1:3]), tmp[4:6])

aggregate(cbind(Cat,Dog,Fish) ~ ind, data=tmp, subset=tmp$values, FUN=sum)

#        ind Cat Dog Fish
#1 Apartment   1   0    1
#2     Condo   0   1    2
#3     House   2   0    0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's always interesting to see the Base version since I'm still relatively new to R and work mostly within the Dplyr+Tidyr world.